# Ajax post request only prints if there are more than one echo statement

Tags: php, ajax, echo

I am using ajax to process a login form. Everything works correctly within the request with a single exception. The data is being submitted to the file `login.php`.

The relative code in that file is below:

```
$dealer = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$a = [];

if (!$dealer) {
    $a['response'] = 'error';
} else {
    $a['response'] = 'ok';
}

$output = json_encode($a);
echo $output;
die();
```

When the script is called directly, the error response is given and echoed to the browser. However, when the values are submitted via post, nothing is returned. If I add another line that echoes a character to the screen anywhere before the die() call, everything echoes as it should including the value of $output.

Any ideas why that is the case and how to correct it?

**Edit:**

The response headers are as follows:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 15:02:00 GMT
>
> Server: Apache
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.11
>
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Length: 20
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=190
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

So based on the Content-Length, the response is being passed back, but it is hidden in some way so that the javascript can't read it, and it isn't viewable in the Chrome Web Developer Tools. If I change the echo line to:

```
echo $output.$output;
```

or if I add a second echo as below:

```
echo $output;
echo $output;
```

the Content-Length changes to 40, and the following is printed:

> {"response":"error"}{"response":"error"}

Comment: That is incorrect. Other output is not erased. As evidenced that when adding a second echo line, all output is displayed.

Comment: But just for kicks, I removed the die(), and the exact same issue occurred. When there is one echo, nothing is returned via ajax. When there is more than one, everything is returned.

Comment: can you please `print_r($output);` instead of echoing it?

Comment: Same problem. Nothing is returned. However, if I echo $output and on the next line print_r($output), I get `{"response":"error"}{"response":"error"}`. So no difference.

Comment: May be it is due to some browser-related bug? Have you tried it in another browser?

Comment: Good idea by basil. Alternatively, close and reopen browser, restart computer, empty browser cache, or uninstall, then re-install browser (sequentially) until hopefully the issue corrects!

Comment: That actually is a good idea, basil, however, Firefox gives the same problem. The Content-Length is there, but the content is not unless I add a non-white-space character to the output (which makes it invalid json)

Comment: Now it looks like some apache/php issue. It accuratly calculates Content-Lenght but somehow forget to print it out =) Have you tried to invoke a minimal working example directly from CLI? I wonder whether it print correct result.

Comment: But no, it is definitely not a php bug, since Apache is in charge of calculating content length, so as it do it right it is provided by a valid content from php, then correctly calculates a length, but failed to send a content itself.

Comment: are you actually 100% sure it is not in the source beeing returned ? and its not just your browser "not rendering"  the content to screen .. ?    try using a curl call via cli to check the response, completely ruling out the browser

Comment: @basil I have not tried from CLI yet. However, if I browse directly to the page in the browser, the correct response is displayed. It is only when the call is made via ajax that the problem occurs.

Comment: @Joseph yes you are right, my bad. Have you tried cURL as Sam Janssens suggested? Just in case recall you how to do it easily - in Chrome DevTools > Network > right click on the request in question > Copy as cURL > run it in terminal.

Comment: @basil Yep. cURL returned `{"response":"error"}` just like the browser does.

Comment: @Joseph,  if you ran right cURL command (with POST method) and the returned response was correct it means the problem is on browser side, doesn't it?

Comment: @basil I would think so, but the issue is cross-browser, and as long as it isn't valid json, the content shows up. Also, the issue only appears via ajax calls.

Comment: @Joseph if the cURL command you have ran was copied from DevToolbar - it is absolutely equivalent to AJAX request, because it would content all the proper headers (x-requested-with=xmlhttprequest) and POST data.

Comment: @basil I understand that, but along those lines, then, do you have any recommendations on where to look for the problem since it is a cross-browser issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly I couldn't reproduce  the bug on my local mashine - all worked as expected. I used php build-in server and it for some reason doesn't send `Content-Length` header. As I understand a minimal working example in your case is `<?php echo '{"response":"error"}';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get your code to work for me after a few little edits. I made up a request with JQuery to imitate an AJAX request from the client.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$dealer = true; // Imitating a successful login.
$a = array(); // '[]' wasn't working on my localhost setup.

if (!$dealer) {
    $a['response'] = 'error';
} else {
    $a['response'] = 'ok';
}

$output = json_encode($a);
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // THIS IS IMPORTANT! It tells Javascript that the body of the returned information is JSON.
echo $output;
exit(); // I prefer to only use die() if I'm echoing something when killing the script, it's just a matter of personal choice.
```

The `header('Content-Type: application/json');` line ensures that the body returned by the PHP script is registered as being JSON formatted by the client.

**My AJAX Test Setup (HTML):**

```
<p>Response: <span id="test">default</span></p>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqxhr = $.ajax("login.php").done(function(e) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = e.response;
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Failed to fetch information.');
    });
</script>
```

I've used jQuery in this answer and I recommend that you use jQuery in your application as it is an amazing Javascript library and can simplify almost anything.

This worked for me and I hope it helps you!

Comment: I had the header line in originally earlier in the script, but took it out due to testing. It has not been required in other times I have done similar things, but I will add it back in to test. My ajax setup is pretty much identical to this one and does use jQuery.

Comment: No change after adding the header line back in.

Comment: @Joseph Hmmmmm... That's strange. That code up there completely worked for me in my localhost environment.

Comment: @Joseph What happens when you access the script from directly in your browser but not as a AJAX request? With all of the parameters of course.

Comment: I mentioned previously when I go directly to the URL in the browser, it displays as it should. Also, when I access the page via cURL, the content is returned and echoed out.

Comment: @Joseph I'm going to put all of the headers in your question into my test script and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91891/discussion-between-deansheather-and-joseph).

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because it likely would have worked in 99.9999% of situations.  I decided to go another route though.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't solve your problem. I'm glad you found your own solution though.

Comment: No worries.  Thank you for all the effort.